# jQuery function after append element

Tags: jquery, append

Can somebody tell me how to append HTML code that have button element and make that button functional? Why is my function not working on appended button?

Here's my code:

```
<div id="attachments">
    <input id="add-attachment" type="button" value="Dodaj kolejny &#x271A;" class="button-custom-3">
    <div class="hr-custom-1"></div>
<div>
    <input type="button" value="Przeglądaj" class="button-custom-1">
    <span>Przykładowa nazwa załączonego pliku.jpg</span>
    <input type="button" value="Usuń &#x2716;" class="button-custom-2 button-remove-attachment">
    <div class="hr-custom-1"></div>
</div>

<div>
    <input type="button" value="Przeglądaj" class="button-custom-1">
    <span>Przykładowa nazwa załączonego pliku.jpg</span>
    <input type="button" value="Usuń &#x2716;" class="button-custom-2 button-remove-attachment">
    <div class="hr-custom-1"></div>
</div>
```

JavaScript functions:

```
$(".button-remove-attachment").click(function(){
    $(this).parent().remove();
});

$("#add-attachment").click(function(){
    var element = $("<div><input type='button' value='Przeglądaj' class='button-custom-1'><span>Przykładowa nazwa załączonego pliku.jpg</span><input type='button' value='Usuń &#x2716;' class='button-custom-2 button-remove-attachment'><div class='hr-custom-1'></div></div>");
    $("#attachments").append(element);       
});
```

Please check it on jsFiddle: https://jsfiddle.net/6f9xhr64/

Comment: please explain in more detail what exactly you want to do .

Comment: check jsFiddle please https://jsfiddle.net/6f9xhr64/

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try using below code

```
$(document).on("click",".button-remove-attachment",function(){
    $(this).parent().remove();
});


$(document).on("click","#add-attachment",function(){
    var element = $("<div><input type='button' value='Przeglądaj' class='button-custom-1'><span>Przykładowa nazwa załączonego pliku.jpg</span><input type='button' value='Usuń &#x2716;' class='button-custom-2 button-remove-attachment'><div class='hr-custom-1'></div></div>");
    $("#attachments").append(element);

});
```

Comment: Use above code, all button's functionality are working fine.I have also created jsfiddle for the same .check this link https://jsfiddle.net/btbboahh/1/

Answer (score 0):

Since your buttons are added dynamically at some point in time, you have to use On() method overload with three parameters. You should refer to this post: [Dynamic Html elements](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1359018/in-jquery-how-to-attach-events-to-dynamic-html-elements)